# In Python Pandas, why is it that replacing all elements in a column will still not change the reported column type?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose we have a dataframe like:

```
people = {"name":["P1", "P2"],"Information 1":[[20, 21],[30, 20]],"Information 2":[[50, 52],[52, 55]]}
df_people= pd.DataFrame(people)
df_people
```

which results in:

```
>>> df_people
  name Information 1 Information 2
0   P1      [20, 21]      [50, 52]
1   P2      [30, 20]      [52, 55]
```

Now suppose I do:

```
df_people['Information 1'][0] = 5
df_people['Information 1'][1] = 2
```

Afterwards, `df_people.info()` still shows that column `Information 1` is still an object and NOT a float, which is should be:

```
>>> df_people.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
name             2 non-null object
Information 1    2 non-null object
Information 2    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.loc[]` instead:

```py
df_people['Information 1'].loc[0] = 5
df_people['Information 1'].loc[1] = 2

df_people.dtypes
```

Output:

```py
name             object
Information 1     int64
Information 2    object
dtype: object
```

I feel like it's just one more reason why not to use array assignment in pandas, and instead go with `.loc[]` or `.iloc[]`.

For the question why - I would say, because it's just simple value assignment, which doesn't trigger anything else. Similar to when you assign value to a list, or in numpy. Using `.loc[]` method will provide you with all the additions you might need- like type correction in this case.

EDIT:

Interestingly - when changing the whole column at once it will also work:

```py
df_people.loc[:, 'Information 1']=[0,1]
```

I.e. it will correct the `dtypes`

Comment: `why not to use array assignment` - but this is exactly what you do in answer...

Comment: correct is `df_people.loc[0, 'Information 1']= 5
df_people.loc[1, 'Information 1'] = 2` - but it not change dtypes

Comment: check last [paragraph](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: I think partially- cause in order to retrieve rows -I do ```.loc[]``` but then to get columns I keep the assignment. Odd that these 2 behave differently in terms of correcting ```dtypes```

Comment: I think your answer should be like yes, it is posible by hacky not recommended way with  `assignment` to `Series`. And why not changed dtypes in `df_people.loc[0, 'Information 1']= 5 df_people.loc[1, 'Information 1'] = 2` then it should be bug? no idea...

Comment: I agree. I think it has to do something with scanning whole column. The completely correct way will also work, when you change whole column at once i.e. ```df_people.loc[:, 'Information 1']=[0,1]```. Otherwise you apparently have to first return ```Series``` and then interact with it through ```.loc[]``` to get ```dtypes``` corrected i.e. ```df_people['Information 1'].loc[0]=0```

Comment: If you want you can create new post for pandas github like bug, pandas developers should explain this